# Какое подлежащее в этом предложении?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Предложение с другого ресурса:

***У него было тончайшее чувство юмора.***

1. Там искали **сказуемое**, но вопрос о **подлежащем** здесь более интересен. Что является **предикативной основой**?
2. **Дополнительные вопросы:**

Как записать предложение, в котором будет составное **именное** сказуемое?

А можно его сделать **(1) безличным и (2) назывным?**

Comment: Очень интересный вопрос для всех, кто интересуется синтаксическим разбором.

Comment: Спасибо. Выглядит предложение как подстава))  Что-то с ним не то...

Comment: У него тончайшее чувство юмора. -- назывное предложение. Безличного тут ничего нет в принципе. Подлежащее тут однозначно. Как тут СИС впендюрить? Никак. Ну только так: Это у него было тончайшее чувство юмора.

Comment: Во всем сомневаюсь...  Первое предложение похоже на эллиптическое, что ж тут назывного?

Comment: Не может быть СИС? Ну тогда парадигму рассмотрите.  Можно измененные варианты на эту тему предлагать.  Просто для сравнения.  Да и контекст тоже.  Ситуацию нарисовать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
У него было тончайшее чувство юмора
```

Здесь подлежащее **чувство**. Это однозначно - все скажут. Проверяется изменением рода подлежащего, с возникающей необходимостью согласовывать род сказуемого:

```
У него был тончайший юмор
```

Это уже явно не безличное предложение.

Хотя вот уже с предложением, есть небольшие сомнения

```
У него во дворе снега было по колено.
```

Здесь синтаксис будет лечить нам про родительный падеж в форме подлежащего или прямо про связку "снега по колено" в форме подлежащего (кстати какое тут подлежащее и какая роль у "по колено"?). Так или иначе здесь просматривается какой-то субъект и его отношение с объектом посредством глагола быть.

С другой стороны, можно рассмотреть схожее предложение:

```
У него во дворе навалило снега по колено.
```

Его можно разобрать по двум разным парадигмам, безличной (рассогласование в роде не позволяет иной трактовки) и личной (согласование в роде не позволяет иной трактовки):

```
У него во дворе навалил снег по колено.
У него во дворе навалило снег по колено.
```

Видим, что тут уже не требуется согласование в роде. Но с глаголом **быть** такое никогда не сработает, потому что глагол **навалить** допускает безличный субъект (навалило ветром), который неявно висит в последнем предложении, а глагол **быть** таких неявных субъектов очевидно не допускает (предложение будет с ошибкой, если добавить к быть, субъекта в творительном).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Голос от меня. Интересно, любопытно!  Но нерешенные вопросы остались, причем   как для подлежащего, так и для сказуемого. Позже я дам свой вариант ответа. Хотелось бы еще кого послушать, сравнить мнения, но молчат-с.

Comment: Я знаю, что скажут. Есть дежурный ответ: чувство — подлежащее, было — сказуемое.  Это у тех, кто грамматику читал.   Но вот что еще есть. (1) Существительное "чувство".  (2) Глагол "быть".  Слова  подозрительные  и многозначные, по словарю проверять надо. Да, еще о предикативных наречиях не надо забывать.   И семантика, которая не особо дружит с грамматикой.  Ему страшно/ у него чувство страха.  А есть еще слово "нет", которое все делает безличным. В общем, так много всего есть, что лучше не думать об этом.  Пусть уж так: чувство — подлежащее, было — сказуемое.

Comment: А я и забыл про отрицательные предложения, типа "у него не было чувства юмора" - безличное вроде, хотя вот тут рассматривают его как личное https://russkayarech.ru/ru/archive/1969-6/50-59. А где оно кстати рассматривается как безличное, у кустовой где-то?

Comment: Да, у Кустовой есть эта тема. Слово "нет" и глаголы с отрицанием, в том числе "не было". Не нашлось, не осталось, не появилось. Отрицательно-бытийное значение.  Семантический субъект в форме Р. п. как обязательный структурный элемент (структурный минимум для таких предложений).